# Iterating over an object in Rails template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, templates, erb

controller:

```
  def show
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
    @ingredients = @recipe.ingredients
    @steps = @recipe.steps
  end
```

template:

```
  <%= @steps.each do |step| %>
    <li>
      <%= step.sequence %>
      <%= step.description %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
```

The array of objects passed to my template is being iterated over and then is showing the actual array of fields at the end (below step 5 in the picture). I want to display properties of each object, not the actual list of objects.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you want not clear but `<%= @steps.to_sentence %>`  or `<%=@steps%>`this will show the array

Comment: change `<%= @steps.each` to `<% @steps.each`.  using `%=` renders to the page as text which is not what you want.

Answer (score 6):

You are doing `<%= @steps.each do |step| %>...<% end %>`, which prints the result of evaluating `each`, which is the receiver `@steps`.

To avoid printing it, change that to `<% @steps.each do |step| %>...<% end %>`.

Comment: Oh gosh, thank you soo much. This is my first day on the rails.